force pip-compile to use installed versions of the dependencies
I noticed that pip-compile generates the requirements.txt file picking the last compatible versions of the dependencies.
For instance, having the following requirements.in file:
boto3

pip-compiles generates the following requirements.txt file
#
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile with Python 3.10
# by the following command:
#
#    pip-compile requirements.in
#
boto3==1.35.28
    # via -r requirements.in
botocore==1.35.28
    # via
    #   boto3
    #   s3transfer
jmespath==1.0.1
    # via
    #   boto3
    #   botocore
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
    # via botocore
s3transfer==0.10.2
    # via boto3
six==1.16.0
    # via python-dateutil
urllib3==2.2.3
    # via botocore


even if I have installed urllib3 1.26.18 in my venv.
I know I could force urllib3 version by setting it into requirements.in but I would prefer pip-compile to take the local versions of the dependencies rather than the most recent compatible ones.
Is there a way to force this behaviour?

You can force pip-compile to use the versions already installed in your virtual environment by running:
pip-compile --no-upgrade

The --no-upgrade flag tells pip-compile to generate the requirements.txt file based on your current package versions, without upgrading them.

I did a test but --no-upgrade refers to an existing requirements.txt, not to a brand new one.

You're right! The --no-upgrade flag works when there's already a requirements.txt file present. If you're starting fresh run pip freeze > requirements.in

If others are wondering this is the solution I found:
pip-compile -c <(pip freeze)

